# How do I use Django/Python to create rows in a table?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to create a html table that has the number of rows and content set, according to what is in Django. I have written the following code:

```
           <h5>Model</h5>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" href="{% url 'create_model' %}?project={{ project.id }}" role="button">Add Model</a>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Entry name</th>
      <th scope="col">Model</th>
      <th scope="col">Outcome</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Entry Name</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Entry Name</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Entry Name</th>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock content %}
```

I can access 'Entry name;' through something like this:

```
 {% for entry in entries %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{entry.name}}</td>
```

How do I set the number of rows I need according to what the database has stored for entry names? For example, if there are two entry names. I want to have double the number of rows, so that the table has the following form:

[image: Table I want]

Comment: Can you elaborate? Your image seems to reflect exactly what your code is supposed to do (create a `<tr><td>{{entry.name}}</td></tr>` for every entry) if you combine your two code snippets, so I don't really understand what your looking for.

Comment: My code at the moment would just show the bill rows of the table. I haven't combined the two snippets yet, as I don't know how. There are variable numbers of entry names depending on the instance.